# Fix spacing between different series in JavaFX line chart

Tags: java, css, javafx

[image]

I want the item spacing to appear more orderly with a constant spacing

How can I do this? I combed through the JavaFX CSS properties and modena css, and I didn't see anything relevant that seemed to work. I only find these properties:

```
.chart-legend {
   -fx-background-color: white
   -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0,1;
   -fx-background-radius: 4,4,3;
   -fx-padding: 6px;
}
```

Comment: looks like each label gets the same amount which is the min that fits the widest. What/how exactly do you want that changed, that is what do you mean by "more oderly"?

Comment: @kleopatra I want the same space between each one. Because if you see the image the third and fourth parameter are very close.

Comment: hmm ... not supported: Legend is-a TilePane which sizes its children uniformly. If I understand you correctly, you want a FlowPane or a HBox - you will have to go dirty, subclass the chart and swap it out for a custom implementation

Comment: @kleopatra Yes like a HBox or similar. Ok I will try to do it the dirty way :D. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend of a Chart is an arbitrary node. It's default implementation is a specialized TilePane, that is its children are sized uniformly across the available width. For a different layout that default implementation can be replaced with a custom legend, f.i. a FlowPane (or HBox).

A quick approach is to subclass LineChart, override updateLegend and replace the default with a custom pane. The example below is dirty in that it relies on implementation details of the default implementation

The custom LineChart:

```
public static class MyLineChart<X, Y> extends LineChart<X, Y> {

    public MyLineChart(Axis<X> xAxis, Axis<Y> yAxis) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
    }

    private TilePane legendAlias;
    private FlowPane legendReplacement;

    @Override
    protected void updateLegend() {

        // let super do the setup
        super.updateLegend();
        Node legend = getLegend();
        if (legend instanceof TilePane) {
            legendAlias = (TilePane) legend;
            legendReplacement = new FlowPane(10, 10);
            setLegend(legendReplacement);
        }
        if (legendAlias != null && legendAlias.getChildren().size() > 0) {
            legendReplacement.getChildren().setAll(legendAlias.getChildren());
            legendAlias.getChildren().clear();
            setLegend(legendReplacement);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are awesome! It works perfectly! Thank you for all